# Why are so many answers posted as comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

In tex.stackexchange, it's pretty common for users to post comments that answer the question.  Sometimes there are several good answers posted as comments, but nothing posted as an answer.  This doesn't happen as often in other stackexchange forums in which I participate.  I don't understand why this practice is common here.  It makes it difficult to know which questions already have answers from the question list.  That's undesirable if I think I might have an answer, because I open the question and discovered it already has good answers.  It's also undesirable if I hope that someone has answered the question, so that I can find out the answers, since it appears that the question has not been answered. (For "I" substitute anyone, obviously.)  Finally, I think the people posting such "comment answers" deserve the chance to get credit for the answers.  Maybe they don't need the points, but I still think they deserve credit.

Any thoughts about this?  Thanks.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Why do people answer in comments?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3238/15717) and Related [Adding the “accepted” mark to a question or to a comment](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3683/15717)

Comment: [How to end the unanswered status of really solved question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3640/how-to-end-the-unanswered-status-of-really-solved-questions-in-the-comments?lq=1)

Comment: I'm interested that both you and the person writing the earlier, probably duplicate, question think that there are 'lots' of questions answered in comments. Our answer rate is currently around 97 %, so there are not really many cases where this can apply.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  @JosephWright, I see from the dupe question [Why do people answer in comments?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/why-do-people-answer-in-comments) that most questions _eventually_ get answers posted.  What concerns me is that new questions are often thoroughly answered in comments, but don't appear to be answered.  I'll take my further discussion to [Why do people answer in comments?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/why-do-people-answer-in-comments).